# How to increase performance for listing nested Doctrine entities

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine

I am using `Zend Framework 3` and `Doctrine2` in this project.

I have a nested entity which is build like a tree hierarchy.

```
[Project] 1 - n [WorkOrders] 1 - n [WorkOrderItems]
```

Every `WorkOrderItem` has a status - to simplify for the example that status can be 1 for not finished or 2 for finished. I now want to display the progress of the project by iterating over all `WorkOrderItems` and calculate the percent like so:

```
$finishedWorkOrderItems = 0;
$totalWorkOrderItems = 0;
foreach ($this->getWorkOrders() as $workOrder) {
    foreach ($workOrder->getWorkOrderItems() as $workOrderItem) {
        if ($workOrderItem->getStatus() == WorkOrderItem::STATUS_FINISHED) {
            $finishedWorkOrderItems++;
        }
        $totalWorkOrderItems++;
    }
}
return 100 / $totalWorkOrderItems * $finishedWorkOrderItems;
```

When displaying a list of 50 Projects the loadtime until the View is completely rendered is very high - between 7 and 9 seconds. When rendering the list without the progress the render time is significantly lower - between 0.5 and 2s.

I tried to use a custom `DQL` for the project and join the needed data in the select statement like so :

```
$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder
        ->select(['p', 'o', 'oi'])
        ->from(Project::class, 'p')
        ->join('p.orders', 'o')
        ->join('o.orderItems', 'oi')
        ->groupBy('p');
```

Which gave me no measurable performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get your total count directly from DQL instead of a nested loop

```
SELECT p,
COUNT(DISTINCT  o.id) AS totalOrders,
COUNT(oi.id) AS totalOrdersItems,
SUM(CASE WHEN oi.status = 'some status' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalWorkedOrdersItems
FROM Bundle\Entity\Project p
LEFT JOIN p.orders o
LEFT JOIN o.orderItems oi
GROUP BY p.id
```