# Is this DQL right

Tags: dql

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$query->select('(case when (e.startDate>=CURRENT_DATE()) then count(es.event)  END) upComingEvent);
$query->from('Entities\ES','es')
    ->leftjoin('Entities\E', 'e', 'with', 'e.id=es.event');
$query->addGroupBy('es.userId');

$query->addOrderBy('upComingEvent' , 'desc');
```

I am trying to find upcoming event of any user and write this DQL which throws exception

> Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException with message "printing above dql"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to correct your `case` clause and move case statement inside `count()` method to count only rows where provided criteria is met.

```
$query->select('count(case when e.startDate>=CURRENT_DATE() then 1 end) upComingEvent);
```

[Formulating complicated Doctrine2 DQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518728/formulating-complicated-doctrine2-dql-query/25606307#25606307)

Or with [conditional sum()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198440/853360)

```
$query->select('sum(case when e.startDate>=CURRENT_DATE() then 1 else 0 end) upComingEvent);
```